# Under which cases, the JVM will restart

Tags: java, jvm

anyone knows when the JVM will restart or shutdown? Will it be shutdown when I have Java code running?

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731398/can-a-java-exe-jvm-restart-itself-somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when the JVM will restart

Never.

> or shutdown?

When `System.exit()` is called, or all non-daemon threads have exited, or when it encounters an unexpected signal.

Answer (score 2):

The JVM will restart when you restart it.

It will shutdown when

- you call System.exit() (and the shutdown hooks have been called)
- all the non-deamon threads complete.
- the system crashes due to a bug in a native library.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM shuts down if it crashes (its a given...)

Otherwise it will shutdown if there are no more running threads (deamon threads are ignored), or someone is activly shutting the jvm down (calling System.exit() or Runtime.getRuntime().shutdown())